# mongo:db.users.find({"addressse.0.state":"NY"}) write in php?

Tags: php, mongodb

In learing mongo with php,I have a tiny problem,
that is all,any help would be great appreciated！

Comment: Are we supposed to guess your problem ?

Comment: This might help: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php (more specifically: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.criteria.php)

Answer (score 3):

You need to read this [MongoPHPQueries Page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.queries.php) and probably before that you need to do as @RocketHazmat said and start with this [MongoPHP Tutorial](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php).

But here is something that might help you with the data you are trying to find.

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array("addressse.0.state" => "NY"));
```

The above will give you a cursor allowing you to iterate over each record that is returned. Hope this helps.

**FYI** - You need more than just that line above to get that to work. So follow the links.